# Post-commit hook fails in Visual SVN Server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

I have added a post-commit hook to my Visual SVN Server that updates my web root folder. I have the following in the commit-hook:

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\svn.exe" update "D:\wamp\www\xix" --username xone --password xxx
```

Running this from within the command-line works, but when I commit changes in my project from the client program, I get always the error:

> Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output: svn:
>   E720005: Error resolving case of 'D:\wamp\www\xix'

Why is this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is **D:** a mapped network drive? Network drives are mapped on per-user basis and are not accessible by service accounts. VisualSVN Server runs under NETWORK SERVICE account, by default.

Comment: Also, check that you are running the client program with Administrator-level privileges.

Comment: @SameerSingh you are wrong, it does not matter in this case at all.

Comment: Hmmm I've had funnies with this when the client wasn't running as Admin, but I think you're right. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Several things:

- The post-commit hook has no access to your client's workspace.
- When you run the command from the command line, you're a different user than the user the server running the command. The error number `E720005` usually points to a user who doesn't have permission to update a file inside their working directory. That user may have permission to read from the repository, but not necessarily to write to the working directory.
- Many environment variables are purposefully munged when the hook is executed. It could be that your environment variables like `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%` are not what you think they are.

Comment: @user2209901 - When someone comes up with a solution on Stackoverflow, it's good to _accept_ their answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of that post. It earns the person who answered your questions reputation points which then can be used to _impress the babes_.